# Trouble in Team Viewer VPN Connection

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer

I have completed initial vpn connection setup. It has connected. I have tested with ping and it is ok. My problem is, when I want to start file transfer in VPN it asks for username & password. So what is the user name? I have tried giving Computer-Name/User-Name. I have found my Computer Name by going to Control Panel/System/ & clicking 'Computer Name' tab & username from user accounts or it is shown when I login in windows account (Please correct me if the above procedure is wrong). But what is the password? I have tried giving the account password but it always give 'The username or password is incorrect.'

**My Question: How to find the username & password?**

**For Information:** 
a) I have Team Viewer 7 installed in one Windows XP PC & one Windows 8 PC. I like to create a secure connection between these two PCs.

b) The two PCs are connected in the same local network via a router.

Please ask if you need additional information.

Comment: You need username and password of the remote machine. Have you seen this document https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teamviewer.com%2Fen%2Fres%2Fpdf%2Ffirst_steps_TV7_unattended_access_en.pdf&ei=rG96UoCzM6uA7Qa7sYC4Dg&usg=AFQjCNEdVSqdLA5bV53noFXiQYQbTfeK1g&bvm=bv.55980276,d.ZGU

Comment: Do you have an account with the company behind Team Viwer?